# SQL check with an if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quick question on SQL how can I make a check such as:

```
Alter Table Invoices WITH NOCHECK
ADD CHECK
```

Now this is the part where I want to add a check so that the `column PaymentDate can be null if another column Payment Total is equal to 0` and `also that PaymentDate is not null if Payment Total is greater than 0`.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? MySQL (still, afaik) does not honour check constraints at all (although it happily parses them)

Comment: What's wrong the docs?  What is your specific question?  Look into [conditionals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html), look into [null checking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html), and [alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) syntax.  This is assuming you mean MySQL and not SQL Server.  Read the tag popouts before adding them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
Alter Table Invoices WITH NOCHECK
ADD CHECK (   (PaymentTotal > 0 AND PaymentDate IS NOT NULL) 
           OR (PaymentTotal = 0 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, as usual I was trying to way over complicate this when it did not need to be...